# JSF Nested EXpression language

Tags: jsf

Is it possible to write nested JSF expression? If yes, please give me the syntax.
If No, Is there any possible work around ??

I need this as I need to display column in rich Datatable from hasmap.

```
<rich:column>
 <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Item Number" />
</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.get('key')}" />
</rich:column>
```

In the above example, I cant hardcode 'key' in the expression lang. I need to read from properties file.

Please Help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to write this without trying to nest an expression. This `outputText` displays a value in `properties/bar.properties` using a value in another properties file (`foo`) as the key:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="properties.foo" var="foo" />
<f:loadBundle basename="properties.bar" var="bar" />
<h:outputText value="#{bar[foo['x']]}" />
```

This could also be expressed as `#{bar[foo.x]}`.